# How to parse images from URL and display them in UITableViewCell as columns?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to display downloaded images from XML in tableview with columns.
I have to use `UITableView`, otherwise I would use `UICollectionView` for this type of funcionality right away. I am able to download images from XML and I am displaying columns by `UIStackview` filled with `UIImageView` in custom `UITableViewCell`. Problem is that there is only first downloaded image shown for both columns. I need to somehow distinguish these images and add them to particular place. What's the best practice for this problem?

EDITED: I solve this by passing downloaded images to cell and updating UI. But I am still curious about other approaches, if they are better.

```
for i in startInterval...self.currentBookIndex {
group.enter()
let url = URL(string: books[i].thumbNailURL!)!            
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (imgData, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
       print(error!)
       return
    }

     DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
     if cell.tag == indexPath.row {
     let tmpImage = UIImage(data: imgData!)
         if let image = tmpImage {
              downLoad.append(image)
         }
         cell.bookImage = tmpImage
         cell.updateUI(withIndex: self.currentBookIndex, imageWithURL: url)
      }
      })
      self.group.leave()
}).resume()
self.group.notify(queue: .main) {
print(downLoad.count)
}
```

There are right images in the download array, I need to display them in the UIImageView. There is always only first of 2 displayed, if I have 2 columns. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of UI? I think it would be easier to understand how help you.

Comment: You are using `UITableView` with columns that mean per row you have 2 `UIImageView`. So must have some flag or tag to identify that image views right ? So you can assign image to image views by identifying their tags. In code you have shared what is the `cell` : `UIImageView` of `UITableviewCell`. Also it is showing only one image per cell and that is `cell.bookImage` where is the other one ? Because comparing cell tag to index path row is true for both the column. So you must have 2 separate image view with 2 separate tag.

Comment: I am programatically creating UIImageView in updateUI method.